# Find distribution function of a PDF

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I'm learning probability and trying to solve the following problem:

Find distribution function of:

$p(x)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
0 & x<2 \\ 
 \frac{A}{(1-x)^2}&x\geq 2 
\end{matrix}\right.$

Could you please tell me how would I do so? What do I need to calculate? Thanks

Comment: Do you know the definition of a [distribution function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function) and [how it relates to the density function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function#Definition)?

Comment: @angryavian I'm not sure I understand it correctly, it's my first problem regarding distribution function.

Comment: $$\int_{-\infty}^x p(y)dy$$

Comment: @Andrei Could you please show me how would the distribution function look in this case? So that I know how to correctly apply the definition

Answer (score 0):

From the definition of the distribution,
$$D(x)=\int_{-\infty}^xp(y)dy$$
Since $p$ is $0$ for $x\lt 2$, $D(x)=0$ for $x<2$. For $x>2$ $$D(x)=\int_2^x\frac A{(1-y)^2}dy=\int_2^x\frac A{(y-1)^2}dy$$
Change the variable $z=y-1$, with $dz=dy$. The new integration limits will be $1$ and $x-1$.
$$D(x)=A\int_1^{x-1}\frac{dz}{z^2}=-A\frac 1z\bigg|_1^{x-1}=A\left(1-\frac1{x-1}\right)=A\frac{x-2}{x-1}$$
Notice that $D(\infty)$ must be $1$, so $A=1$

Answer (score 0):

First calculate $A$ setting

$$\int_2^{\infty}f(x)dx=1$$

Finding $A=1$

Then apply the definition where

$$F_X(x)=\int_2^x\frac{1}{(1-t)^2}dt=\Bigg(1+\frac{1}{1-x}\Bigg)\mathbb{1}_{[2;\infty)}(x)$$

Answer (score 0):

For a valid pdf the following condition must hold: $\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} p(x) \,dx =1$. That means in your case

$$\int\limits_{2}^{\infty} \frac{A}{(1-x)^2} \,dx =1$$

Simplifiying the equation

$$A\int\limits_{2}^{\infty} (1-x)^{-2} \,dx =1$$

$$A\cdot \left[(1-x)^{-1}\right]_2^{\infty} =1$$

$$A\cdot \left(0-(1-2)^{-1}\right)=1$$

$$A\cdot \left(0+1\right)=1\Rightarrow A=1$$